# Events happening in two places in one short story?

Tags: structure

Events happening in two places in one short story?

Is this ethical to happen in one short story (craftwise) or is it unprofessional to break the linear flow?

Eg: A wakes up thinks, wait get dressed and leave to place X. In place X a bunch of characters discuss an issue and character A walks in to learn the conclusion.

''I have never heard that the events in a short story must all take place in
the same location.''

Can events in a short story happen (in the latter half of the story) without, in the absence of the protagonist?

He enters at the end of the story to learn what has happened to 'B' who just disappeared without a trace. He reminisces his acquaintanceship with B in the first half.

Comment: I have never heard that the events in a short story must all take place in the same location. A short story is short, that is all.

Comment: Is "ethical" the word you meant? I'm having trouble understanding what the issue would be.

Comment: =Totally unprofessional

Comment: There are no rules for a short story. You can tell any story you want.

Comment: You're fine. Just write your story.

Comment: This is unclear. You're asking at least two different questions here - switching locations, and moving away from your protagonist. And your phrasing is very confusing. I'm afraid I need to close this. You can edit the question, or clarify here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Not only can this happen, it's frequently *assumed* that it happens. You can't show two sets of events occurring at the same moment textually (unless you're doing some kind of weird formatting, and the reader can't read them simultaneously anyway), so you write about one set of events and then the other. Your time cues will advise the reader if events in Location X are before, during, or after events in Location Y. Having A get dressed and travel to Location Y and come in at the end of the conversation is an excellent way of showing simultaneous events in written sequence. You're totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last part of the question, the protagonist doesn't have to be present at every event. All that is necessary is that every event *affects* the protagonist.

The "second half" could be about the group of people deciding the *fate* of the protagonist. It may be a legal tribunal passing judgment and sentence, or it could even be a social "judgment," of "we don't want to have anything to do with this guy again," and why.

And it could be that this group is passing judgment at the same time that the protagonist is shown doing an example of what the group is judging him for (e.g., using drugs, heavy drinking, hanging with the "wrong" people for some value of "wrong").

Comment: Changed. Still considerable offenses but doesn't go quite so far.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: And I changed "selling drugs" to "using" drugs.

Comment: sure, I'll go with that.